java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalLifecycleOwner not present
I get an java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalLifecycleOwner not present error when I collectAsState() or collectAsStateWithLifecycle(). I do not know what is wrong. This previously worked, however since I made a switch and some dependencies update it stopped working. The error is as follows:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalLifecycleOwner not present
at androidx.lifecycle.compose.LocalLifecycleOwnerKt$LocalLifecycleOwner$1.invoke(LocalLifecycleOwner.kt:26)
at androidx.lifecycle.compose.LocalLifecycleOwnerKt$LocalLifecycleOwner$1.invoke(LocalLifecycleOwner.kt:25)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getCurrent(ValueHolders.kt:29)
at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolders.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalMapKt.read(CompositionLocalMap.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.consume(Composer.kt:2135)
at androidx.lifecycle.compose.FlowExtKt.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(FlowExt.kt:182)
at com.codejockie.wani.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:47)
at com.codejockie.wani.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:45)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:186)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:139)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3302)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3235)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:725)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1071)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:633)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:619)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1289)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:164)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:320)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:198)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:121)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1364)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:22257)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3494)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3501)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3207)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9789)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1399)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1408)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1008)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:938)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1382)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

Not sure this is a problem but I recently switched from an Intel MacBook to an M1.
Cloned my project and continued work where I left off then updated the dependencies since Android studio gave a hints there were updates.
My dependencies are as follows:
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-text")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    // DataStore
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore:1.1.1")
    // Glide
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-beta01")
    // Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.51")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.2.0")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
    // Kotlin Serialization
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1")
    // Lifecycle
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.8.0")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    // Media
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-session:1.3.1")
    // OkHttp
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.11.0"))
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
    // Protobuf
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0")
    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
    // WorkManager
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0")

    // Test dependencies
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.7.7")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.work:work-testing:2.9.0")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.6.1")
}

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val mainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val uiState by mainViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

            App(
                closeApp = { this.finish() },
                appState = uiState,
            )
        }
    }
}


Update: The issue has been resolved in Lifecycle version 2.8.3 or above.

That error lines up with this issue, due to a mismatch of Compose and Lifecycle versions. You are using Lifecycle 2.8.0, which right now is incompatible with stable Compose versions. Once Compose 1.7.0 becomes stable, you can upgrade to use it with Lifecycle 2.8.0, and (hopefully) this problem goes away.
I recommend dropping back to Lifecycle 2.7.0 from the 2.8.0 that you are using now. Alternatively, you can try the documented workarounds.

I feel like Google should have been a lot more explicit in the release notes of 2.8.0, at least to say that it was only compatible with Compose 1.7+. Especially as there are no compile time errors

Android Studio shouldn't be suggesting upgrading to 2.8.0. I think that is what will catch most people.

@BarryIrvine They curated the BOM to resolve such problems but here we are. Google will never get it done. They just keep creating workaround-like solutions which ends up being resolved in stackoverflow almost all the time.

@Farid I'm using the BOM but the lifecycle components aren't part of the compose bom

Lifecycle 2.8.2 was just released which should fix the issue - the changelist appears to use reflection to access the older API (seems to be a stopgap solution for now).

I have upgraded to 2.8.2 and the app is working in the debug mode, but in release mode, the app is crashing.

@DibyenduMahata Lifecycle 2.8.3 was released to fix that issue from what I can tell

With @CommonsWare answer, I was able to find the cause of this issue which was that I had updated androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose and androidx.compose:compose-bom. For the former I updated it to 2.8.0 and the latter to 2024.05.00. Based on the information provided in the issue tracker at here, LocalLifecycleOwner has been moved from androidx.compose.ui to lifecycle-runtime-compose. Since I didn't want to use a beta version of the compose-ui package, to get my code working again I applied the suggested fix number 2 provided here:

Map androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner (Compose 1.6) to androidx.lifecycle.compose.LocalLifecycleOwner (Lifecycle 2.8). Here's an example:
CompositionLocalProvider(
    androidx.lifecycle.compose.LocalLifecycleOwner provides androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
) {
  // ...
}


Please note that when using Navigation Compose, this may be required on each navigation page (for more details, refer to comment #11).


UPDATE
Lifecycle 2.8.3 has fixed the above issue therefore the workaround I posted previously is no longer needed. I tested the fix with the same app where I originally encountered the issue.

This was supposedly fixed with 2.8.2 - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_28_2

Fixed CompositionLocal LocalLifecycleOwner not present errors when using Lifecycle 2.8.X with Compose 1.6.X or earlier - you can now use Lifecycle 2.8.2 with any version of Compose without any workarounds required. (aosp/3105647, b/336842920)

as Dibyendu Mahata pointed out. The stacktrace looks like this:
The
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 19006
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalLifecycleOwner not present
   at O2.d.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
   at id.p.getValue(Unknown Source:20)
   at F0.r.L(Unknown Source:30)
   at F0.q.m(Unknown Source:4)
   at X6.P5.a(Unknown Source:10)
   at com.myapp.MyActivity$a.b(Unknown Source:53)
   at com.myapp.MyActivity$a.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
   at N0.b.invoke(SourceFile:7)
   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.a(Unknown Source:24)
...

The change says:

A custom Proguard rule has been added to prevent the obfuscation of
androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner when using
Compose 1.6.*. This ensures the reflection approach works correctly.

But it appears those rules aren't propgating, or don't work in all cases.
The google ticket for this is:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/346808608
and the fix is on:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/3133056
The revised proguard rules are:
-if public class androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt {
    public static *** getLocalLifecycleOwner();
}
-keep public class androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt {
    public static *** getLocalLifecycleOwner();
}

I'm going to attempt to add these rules and see if my release build will work. Will update tomorrow.

Tried the exact ProGuard rules you posted and they work perfectly. Thanks for posting them! Looking forward to the bugfix release of lifecycle that makes them obsolete.

Yep, working good here too.  Looks like they're in no hurry to push out a fix.  At least this time there's a workaround besides downgrading!

This is now fixed in 2.8.3: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.8.3

Yep, confirmed, the rules are correct in that release.

For Kotlin Multiplatform projects using Jetbrains Compose (org.jetbrains.compose), these worked:
[versions]
compose-plugin = "1.7.0-alpha02"
androidx-lifecycle = "2.8.0"

Note: This is to be put in libs.versions.toml file (aka Version Catalog)
